# Modified Heat Equation: k is not a constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Given the heat equation,
$$
u_{t} = ku_{xx},
$$
how do we modify the solution below (when $k$ is a constant)
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y)e^{\frac{-(x-y)^{2}}{4kt}} dy
$$
to solve the equation also for $k = k(t)$? Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that the heat equation is only well-posed for $k>0$.  So, you need to keep in mind that you time-dependent coefficient $k(t)>0$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 2):

The solution does not change much, denote $K(t) = \int_0^t k(z)\,dz$, then the solution is

$$u(x,t) = g(x) \ast \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{4K(t)}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi K(t)}}$$

I omit the details because this is obviously a homework question, but my hint is to notice how the Fourier Transform does not care about $t$.